# Bibliography after each chapter - classicthesis - LYX

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, subdividing, classicthesis

I'd like to insert a bibliography for each chapter associated to different `.bib` files. I'm using the `classicthesis` for LYX which has a unique Bibliography.lyx in the appendix.

I have tried with `Insert--List/TOC--Bibtex Bibliography` at the and of every chapter without any success (a lot of ? ? ?)
Any suggestions?
Thank's a lot
Lucio

Comment: This is usually done with the `chapterbib` (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) package, or seldom vith the `multibib` one. But as a non-Lyx user, I don't know how you can use it in `LyX`